# I get an error when trying to make a payment with MercadoPago and credit card

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm using the following code to process a payment with MercadoPago and credit card:

```
$mp = new MP($access_token);

$payment = array();
$payment["transaction_amount"] = 100.00;
$payment["token"] = $token;

$result = $mp->post("/v1/payments", $payment);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

I already have the credit card token, but still I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Params Error - 1: Params Error'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: where does the value in $token come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old post, but it can help someone ....

Try to catch the exception so you can handle it and debug it more easily.

I´ve been able to catch it adding:

```php
  // import
  use \MP;
  use \MercadoPagoException;

  // try payment
  try {
      $payment = $this->mp->post("/v1/payments", $this->paymentData);        
  }
  catch (MercadoPagoException $e) {

      $paymentError = new \stdClass();
      $paymentError->parsed = $this->parseException($e->getMessage());
      $paymentError->data = $e->getMessage();
      $paymentError->code = $e->getCode();
  }

  // parse the excepetion "message" to get the code and detail, if exists
  private function parseException($message) {
     $error = new \stdClass();
     $error->code = 0;
     $error->detail = '';
     $posA = strpos($message, '-');
     $posB = strpos($message, ':');
     if($posA && $posB) {
        $posA+=2;
        $length = $posB - $posA;
        // get code
        $error->code = substr($message, $posA, $length);
        // get message
        $error->detail = substr($message, $posB+2);
    }
    return $error;
}
```